# Can't install postgresql ver. 11 client on RHEL7

Tags: rhel, software-installation, yum, docker, postgresql

My system on server is:

```
$  lsb_release -d
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)
```

Generally I have a Dockerized running postgres:11 database on this server and roughly speaking I need to create a database dump from it.

By typing:

```
$ sudo yum install postgresql
```

I can install postgresql clinet (that includes pg_dump, psql, etc) in version 9. But it can't create a dump from postgresql:11 database, so I found advice in: https://www.symmcom.com/docs/how-tos/databases/how-to-install-postgresql-11-x-on-centos-7

I did step-by-step:

```
step 1: $ sudo yum update -y  # I didn't sudo reboot as I wanted to avoid server to not start again and ghaving to ask IT support for restarting it for me

step 2: $ sudo rpm -Uvh https://yum.postgresql.org/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm

step 3: $ sudo yum install postgresql11 -y
```

What's weird - for the first time it installed and worked. However, after logout/login I still had originally preinstalled `postgresql:9` as the first choice, so I removed all postgresql with `yum remove postgresql postgresql11`

I tried again to do execute above steps from 1-3 but I get:

```
$ sudo yum install postgresql11 -y
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos
This system is not registered with RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
You can use rhn_register to register.
Red Hat Satellite or RHN Classic support will be disabled.
No package postgresql11 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Can you help me why the package postgresql11 isn't seen when I try yo install it again?

I tried to clean up cache of yum but doesn't help.

Logs from `yum list`:

```
$ sudo yum list | grep postgresql
This system is not registered with RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
You can use rhn_register to register.
Red Hat Satellite or RHN Classic support will be disabled.
postgresql.x86_64                    9.2.24-2.el7_7           @GSS-RHEL7
postgresql-devel.x86_64              9.2.24-2.el7_7           @GSS-RHEL7
postgresql-libs.x86_64               9.2.24-2.el7_7           @GSS-RHEL7
postgresql11-libs.x86_64             11.7-1PGDG.rhel7         @pgdg11
qt-postgresql.x86_64                 1:4.8.7-4.el7            @GSS-RHEL7
qt5-qtbase-postgresql.x86_64         5.9.7-2.el7              @GSS-RHEL7
freeradius-postgresql.x86_64         3.0.13-10.el7_6          GSS-RHEL7-optional
libreoffice-postgresql.x86_64        1:5.3.6.1-21.el7         GSS-RHEL7-optional
pcp-pmda-postgresql.x86_64           4.3.2-4.el7_7            GSS-RHEL7
postgresql.i686                      9.2.24-2.el7_7           GSS-RHEL7
postgresql-contrib.x86_64            9.2.24-2.el7_7           GSS-RHEL7
postgresql-devel.i686                9.2.24-2.el7_7           GSS-RHEL7
postgresql-docs.x86_64               9.2.24-2.el7_7           GSS-RHEL7
postgresql-jdbc.noarch               9.2.1002-6.el7_5         GSS-RHEL7
postgresql-jdbc-javadoc.noarch       9.2.1002-6.el7_5         GSS-RHEL7-optional
postgresql-libs.i686                 9.2.24-2.el7_7           GSS-RHEL7
postgresql-odbc.x86_64               09.03.0100-2.el7         GSS-RHEL7
postgresql-plperl.x86_64             9.2.24-2.el7_7           GSS-RHEL7
postgresql-plpython.x86_64           9.2.24-2.el7_7           GSS-RHEL7
postgresql-pltcl.x86_64              9.2.24-2.el7_7           GSS-RHEL7
postgresql-server.x86_64             9.2.24-2.el7_7           GSS-RHEL7
postgresql-static.i686               9.2.24-2.el7_7           GSS-RHEL7-optional
postgresql-static.x86_64             9.2.24-2.el7_7           GSS-RHEL7-optional
postgresql-test.x86_64               9.2.24-2.el7_7           GSS-RHEL7
postgresql-upgrade.x86_64            9.2.24-2.el7_7           GSS-RHEL7-optional
qt-postgresql.i686                   1:4.8.7-4.el7            GSS-RHEL7
qt5-qtbase-postgresql.i686           5.9.7-2.el7              GSS-RHEL7
```

Comment: When you removed the Postgres 11 package, did it also remove the repository package?  I can see you have the `postgresql11-libs` package, so it most likely worked the first time. Also, your system isn’t getting updates from Red Hat so it might not work since your OS is several years out of date.

Comment: I removed it and didn't helped. Only after doing `rpm -Uvh https://yum.postgresql.org/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm --replacepkgs` it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

I am not sure if it is a correct way but I respond with solution with helped me:

From RPM manager I forced to reinstall package with postgresql11 https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2005-September/msg00030.html

by:

`$ rpm -Uvh https://yum.postgresql.org/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm --replacepkgs`

Then I removed originally isntalled postgresql ver. 9

`$ yum remove postgresql`

And in the end:

```
$ sudo yum install postgresql11-server postgresql11 -y
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos
This system is not registered with RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
You can use rhn_register to register.
Red Hat Satellite or RHN Classic support will be disabled.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postgresql11.x86_64 0:11.7-1PGDG.rhel7 will be installed
---> Package postgresql11-server.x86_64 0:11.7-1PGDG.rhel7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                  Arch                                        Version                                                  Repository                                   Size
=================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 postgresql11                                             x86_64                                      11.7-1PGDG.rhel7                                         pgdg11                                      1.7 M
 postgresql11-server                                      x86_64                                      11.7-1PGDG.rhel7                                         pgdg11                                      4.7 M

Transaction Summary
=================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  2 Packages

Total download size: 6.4 M
Installed size: 28 M
Downloading packages:
(1/2): postgresql11-11.7-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                           | 1.7 MB  00:00:00
(2/2): postgresql11-server-11.7-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                    | 4.7 MB  00:00:00
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                                                            8.8 MB/s | 6.4 MB  00:00:00
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : postgresql11-11.7-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                          1/2
  Installing : postgresql11-server-11.7-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                   2/2
  Verifying  : postgresql11-server-11.7-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                   1/2
  Verifying  : postgresql11-11.7-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                          2/2

Installed:
  postgresql11.x86_64 0:11.7-1PGDG.rhel7                                                              postgresql11-server.x86_64 0:11.7-1PGDG.rhel7

Complete!
```

It works for me, maybe adding option `--replacepkgs` to rpm manager will help somebody, but I'm not sure why it is even needed?

Comment: It sounds like you either deleted or disabled the "pgdg11" yum repo.  For what its worth, you could also replace your rpm command with `yum reinstall https://yum.postgresql.org/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm`.